# How to rename a magic function in IPython?

Tags: python, ipython

I'd like to rename `%paste` to something like `%pp` so that it takes fewer keystrokes. I worked out a way to do that but it seems complicated. Is there a better way?

```
def foo(self, bar):
    get_ipython().magic("paste")

get_ipython().define_magic('pp', foo)
```

Comment: Try to use alias for such function, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511386/python-built-in-functions-vs-magic-functions-and-overriding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From IPython 0.13, there's a new `%alias_magic` magic function, which you would use as:

```
%alias_magic pp paste
```

Comment: If I exit IPython and start it again I lose the alias. Do you know a way to make the alias persist across IPython sessions?

Comment: You could put it in a startup script: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#startup-files

Comment: The problem is that "%alias_magic pp paste" isn't valid python syntax. This results in a syntax error when starting ipython: ```echo "%alias_magic pp paste" > ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/paste_alias.py```

Comment: The answer I'm looking for is something like ```from IPython.core.magic import MagicsManager; manager = MagicsManager(); manager.register_alias('pp', 'paste')``` but that is not quite right

Comment: `get_ipython().magics_manager().register_alias('pp', 'paste')` should do it. You can also use magics in a startup file by giving it a `.ipy` extension.

Comment: Great, thank you! FYI I got "magics manager not callable" and changed it to this to work: `get_ipython().magics_manager.register_alias('pp', 'paste')`

Answer (score 3):

use `%alias` magic to do it (if you want it to be permanent use `%store`):

```
In [8]: %alias??

"""Define an alias for a system command.

   '%alias alias_name cmd' defines 'alias_name' as an alias for 'cmd'
   ...
```

Comment: I think that only works for system commands, not IPython magic commands, unfortunately.