# Adding custom objects ignores __getattr__ with operators

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, cpython, getattr

I am trying to create a custom object that passes all non-existent method calls down to a member attribute. This works under normal custom method invocations, but fails when attempting to call arithmetic operators.

Below is a console snippet of an example class, a test function, and a cleaned up disassembly of the test function.

```
>>> class NoAdd(object):
...    member = 0
...    def __getattr__(self, item):
...        print('NoAdd __getattr__')
...        # return getattr(self.member, item)
...        if item == '__add__':
...            return self.member.__add__
>>> def test():
...    print('Call __add__ directly.')
...    NoAdd().__add__(5)  # 5
...    print('Implicit __add__.')
...    NoAdd() + 5  # TypeError
>>> dis(test)
  3           8 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (NoAdd)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             12 LOAD_ATTR                2 (__add__)
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 (5)
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 POP_TOP
  5          28 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (NoAdd)
             30 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             32 LOAD_CONST               2 (5)
             34 BINARY_ADD
             36 POP_TOP
             38 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             40 RETURN_VALUE
>>> test()
Call __add__ directly.
NoAdd __getattr__
Implicit __add__.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 5, in test
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoAdd' and 'int'
```

I thought that the Python interpreter would look for the `__add__` method using the standard procedure of invoking `__getattr__` when the method was not found in the object's method list, before looking for `__radd__` in the int. This is apparently not what is happening.

Can someone help me out by explaining what is going on or helping me find out where in the Python source code I can find what `BINARY_ADD` is doing? I'm not sure if I can fix this, but a workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: If you really need a transparent object proxy where only override certain methods, with the rest forwarded on to the wrapped object, use the ``wrapt`` package. http://wrapt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wrappers.html

Comment: Dunder methods like \_\_add__ are only looked up in the class, never the instance through an operator. You need to define \_\_getattr__ on the proxy's metaclass if you want this to work.

Comment: This is an even better dupe, but I wanted to make the longest possible chain: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38133096/2988730

Answer (score 4):

The methods `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` are only used for recovering attributes when you call then explicitly, by example when you do `foo.bar`. They are not used for implicit invocation.

This behaviour is specified in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)

> **Note:** This method may still be bypassed when looking up special methods
>   as the result of implicit invocation via language syntax or built-in
>   functions.

The reason for such an implementation is explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup).

> Bypassing the `__getattribute__()` machinery in this fashion provides
>   significant scope for speed optimisations within the interpreter, at
>   the cost of some flexibility in the handling of special methods

In conclusion what you are trying to do, *i.e.* using `__getattr__` to redirect implicit special method calls, has been voluntarily sacrificed in favor of speed.

### Inheritance

The behaviour you are describing can be achieved by class inheritance. Although, passing in arguments to your class constructor will require the following fidling with the `__new__` method.

```
class NoAdd(int):

    def __new__(cls, x, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, x)

    def __init__(self, x, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

x = NoAdd(0)

x + 5 # 5
x * 2 # 0
```

### Metaclass

Now, suppose you really need to catch implicit call to special methods. I see very little case where this could be useful, but it is a fun exercise. In this case we can rely on metaclass to fill in missing methods with the ones from `member`.

```
class ProxyToMember(type):

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, name_space):
        super().__init__(name, bases, name_space)

        if hasattr(cls, 'member'):
            proxy_attrs = (attr for attr in dir(cls.member) if not hasattr(cls, attr))

            def make_proxy(attr):

                attr_value = getattr(cls.member, attr)

                def proxy(_, *args, **kwargs):
                    return attr_value(*args, **kwargs)

                if callable(attr_value):
                    return proxy
                else:
                    return property(lambda _: getattr(cls.member, attr))

            for attr in proxy_attrs:
                setattr(cls, attr, make_proxy(attr))

class A(metaclass=ProxyToMember):
    member = 0

class B(metaclass=ProxyToMember):
    member = 'foo'

A() + 1 # 1
B().startswith('f') # True
```

Comment: Your explanation is *almost* correct

Comment: The specific optimization here is that when you do `a + b`, it always calls `type(a).__add__(a, b)` instead of `a.__getattribute__('__add__')(b)`. The first one technically should call `type(type(a)).__getattribute__(type(a), '__add__')`, so you can make the proxy work by messing with the metaclass.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'll go read about this sublety. When you say almost correct, do you mean that something is wrong or that I missed that detail?

Comment: The explanation you provide shows that the bypass is documented, but does not really explain why it happens, so it is not of much value. I am sure that at least one of the answers to the dupes I voted with has a link to the docs that explain the specific case I refer to above.

Comment: FWIW, your section on inheritance is a much nicer way to go about doing this than metaclasses, but technically does not provide a true proxy.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I see, I never knew there actually was a way to catch the implicit calls of magic methods. I'll read the dups you found, thanks!

Comment: I'm still trying to see if there is a way to make this work though. Even if we were to make `NoAdd() + 1` work with metaclass, I don't see how `1 + NoAdd()` can work since we are then calling `int.__add__`. I really do not think OP has the good approach.

Comment: That actually works out of the box. `int.__add__` will raise a `NotImplementedError` since it does not recognize the type and addition will be deferred to your custom type. I'll find you the doc momentarily. If you think about how adding a numpy array to a scalar works, you will see that this is quite intuitive...

Comment: Correct, I just figured it out. No need to find the doc, it just slipped out of my mind that `__add__` would return `NotImplemented` (and not raise `NotImplementedError` if I am correct).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types. Basically, yes, exactly. Then is calls `NoAdd().__radd__(1)` if possible, and defaults to `NoAdd().__add__(1)` if not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167134/discussion-between-olivier-melancon-and-mad-physicist).

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand you.

Why you can't do something like:

```
class MyInt(int):
    pass

def test():
    print(MyInt(5) + 5)

test()
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The reason I cannot do this is because the class must be able to support any type, not just ints.

Comment: @Yos233 do you mean your need member to be dynamic?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon, he want write Wrapper for any type in Python with inheritance all attributes.

Comment: I added an example of that in my answer above, it was fun

Answer (score -1):

After some more intense research (and following some initially unlikely trails) I found my answer. My thought process didn't come up with the same search keywords, which is why I didn't find these before. My question could probably be considered a duplicate of one of the ones linked below.

I found the simplest/best explanation for why this happens [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511386/python-built-in-functions-vs-magic-functions-and-overriding?noredirect=1&lq=1). I found some good references for resolving this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057669/how-can-i-intercept-calls-to-pythons-magic-methods-in-new-style-classes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637254/intercept-operator-lookup-on-metaclass). The links in [Oliver's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49356663) answer are also helpful.

In summary, Python does not use the standard method lookup process for the magic methods such as `__add__` and `__str__`. It looks like the workaround is to make a `Wrapper` class from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057669/how-can-i-intercept-calls-to-pythons-magic-methods-in-new-style-classes).

Comment: You can just vote to close your own question. As it stands, your "answer" is link-only at best. It has no content of its own.

Comment: As you should be able to see, I have already done that, and marked my question as a duplicate. My answer is to provide closure to this question.

Comment: It looks like you flagged your own answer instead of clicking on the "anwers my question" link that appears in the yellow box.